# Radio button drop down pop up window fee clearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons. When you click the first radio button (Yes) it has a drop down that opens up a pop up window and allows you to add a plate. If the user accepts a plate there is no way for the user to then change there mind and hit no to remove the fee..

Its fine how the user can change the plate and the fees change but the part I am stuck at is if the user decides they do not want the plate and they click the radio button (no) it does not remove the fee..

I have it set up to clear the drop down selection but that does not do the fee part. Can some one please assist?

Also I added the checkbox because I do not want it to completely clear all the fees only the one from the drop down selection.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice it would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/e1ewx5jv/

```js
var specialFee = 0;

$(function(){   //added by me
        $('#IRF').click(function(){   
           calculateTotal();   
        });
    });


function initialRegFee()
{
    var initialFee=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var iRF = document.getElementById('IRF');
    if(iRF.checked==true)
    {
        initialFee=225;
    }
    return initialFee;
}

function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = initialRegFee();
    titleFees += specialFee;
    

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {
                
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-title').html($('option:selected', this).data('name'));
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('')
    .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/><br/><br/>                 Would you like to add this license plate for: $' + $('option:selected', this).data('price') + ' ?')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });
                
        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            specialFee = $('option:selected').data('price');
            calculateTotal();
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });

function showhideSPForm(SP) {
    if (SP == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div8").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div9").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (SP == "No") {
        document.getElementById("div9").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div8").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("SPECIAL").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    calculateTotal();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
Check if
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="IRF" 
  name='IRF' 
  />

<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="SP" id="SP" required="yes" onclick="showhideSPForm(this.value)"/><label for="SP">Yes</label>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="No" name="SP" id="noSP" onclick="showhideSPForm(this.value)"/><label for="noSP">No</label>

   <div id="div8" style="display:none">
<div class="clearfix"> 
    <select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL">
  <option>Please Select</option>
    <option 
      data-name="Animal Friend" 
      data-img="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" 
      data-price="30" 
      value="1">Animal Friend</option>
   <option 
      data-name="Aquaculture" 
      data-img="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" 
      data-price="25" 
      value="2">Aquaculture</option>
   <option 
      data-name="Protect Our Oceans" 
      data-img="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" 
      data-price="20" 
      value="3">Protect Our Oceans</option>
</select>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specialty Plate</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
       </div>
    </div>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
      
<div id="div9" style="display:none">
<!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
</div>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you did not reset specialFee to 0.

```
function showhideSPForm(SP) {
    if (SP == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div8").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div9").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (SP == "No") {
        document.getElementById("div9").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div8").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("SPECIAL").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    specialFee = 0;
    calculateTotal();
}
```